# How does erlang handle large async process?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

How does erlang handle async processes such as logging or writing to mnesia for tables with high write rate? I'm spawning a new process for each write/log and tested with gen_server to handle the logging process itself. The memory of the gen_server process quickly build up and causes the erlang to crash.

What would be the way to handle processes like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use pool of processes as workers to achieve this.If you use one process then message queue will keep on increasing and processing will be delayed.

- Spawn pool of processes(e.g. 10)
- Divide rate between these processes

This way you can handle high load.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To create a pool of processes, is the number of processes within the pool defined at the start of the application or are new processes spawn as needed? Would unused process be terminated if there are more than enough processes running?

Comment: Define number of processes in the start of application.Divide load in between those processes.Processes will be terminated when application stops.